# Validating number field that has capital letters in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, numbers, money-rails

I am trying to validate the entry a  user makes in an amount field.

The field is  amount_money

This field is  a string which is validated on form submission

```
 monetize :amount, :as => :amount_money
 validates :amount, numericality: {only_integer: true}
 validates :amount_money, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0}
 validate :amount_money_within_limit
 validate :is_a_valid_number
```

I want to ensure there are no letters or symbols and that the  amount is  in an acceptable range.

the code  to do this  is

```
def amount_money_within_limit
    if amount_money && amount_money.cents > 10_000_00 
        errors.add(:amount_money, 'cannot exceed $10,000.')
    end
    if amount_money && amount_money.cents < 1_00 
      errors.add(:amount_money, 'Problem with Amount')
    end
end
```

this works great for input  numbers, of numbers and letters,  of letters,  of special characters  but

If  I try Bob - the validation kicks in
but if I try BBob - the validation is  bypassed.

If the input  contains 2 Capital letters next to each other - it fails.
I've tried a downcase - but that doesn't suit as the field is monetized (money gem) - and the downcase screws up  if there is valid input.

If the input to the field contains two uppercase letters - all the validations are bypassed  So  something like AA  is not  caught  by any on the above validations

Comment: look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality)

Comment: What is `amount_money`? How is it defined? How is it assigned? You talk about trying `"Bob"`, but you presumably mean a string, and string's don't have `cents` methods. Please add more of the relevant code.

Comment: note that 1_00 is different from 1.00. 1_00 = 100

Comment: the validation methods pointed to by Sam D do not explain why the validations I am using work for a  mix of letters and numbers, and for characters - but do not work if there are two capital letters.

Regarding 1_00 being 100  -  the point would be that DD (or any other non numeric combination would be less than "a number"

Comment: Do you use this gem https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use regular expressions? Something like this:

```
def is_a_valid_number? amount_money
  amount_money =~ /\d+/
end
```

Comment: Ruby is not my native language - so I am having a  problem with implementing this.  

I also need it to be  in a validation format 
so
if {validation check fails}
present graceful  error
end
and then this would be called when the form is submitted

Comment: You can use regular expressions in any language. If you are new to Ruby than you first need to read about validations in Rails, if that doesn't help you then use regexp.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have put 1 validation on the wrong field, you should've put validations only on `amount` field (your real db field), and not on the `amount_money` which is automagical field from `rails-money` gem. I'll apply [their documentation](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails#numericality-validation-options) on numerical validations to your case:

```
monetize :amount,
  :numericality => {
    :only_integer => true,
    :greater_than_or_equal_to => 1_00,
    :less_than_or_equal_to => 10_000_00
  }
```

You won't need any other custom validations with this setup.